# How to make non-continuous sequence with [1, N] integers?

Tags: algorithm, sequence

I have to make a non-continuous integer sequence `a_1, a_2, ..., a_n` which satisfies

`{a_1, a_2, ..., a_n} ∈ [1, n]`

`|a_i - a_(i-1)| > 1`

How to make it? I appreciate you a hint or some help. Thanks :)

Comment: `1,3,5,...,2k-1,2,4,...,2k` (unless of course you want random, and then - indicate it explicitly). Also - indicate if the sequence should be a *permutation* (if not, `1,3,1,3,1,...` will also do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When there're less than 4 elements, it is impossible to do.

When there're 4 or more elements, we can construct the sequence like this:

if n is even:

```
[n-1, n-3, ... , 1, n, n-2, ..., 2]
```

if n is odd:

```
[n, n-2, ..., 1, n-1, n-3, ..., 2]
```

Now that n is equal or large than 4, |1-n| = |n-1| >= 3, |1-(n-1)| = |1-n+1| = |n| >= 4, the sequence satisfies the constraint.